# typescript object dynamic key type

Tags: typescript, object, typescript-typings

I have some coding style about Typescript object types, following is a sample:

```
interface Stats {
  total: number;
  count: number;
  average: number;
}

interface Groups {
  [name: string]: Stats;
}

const groups: Groups = {
  someGroupName: {
    total: 30,
    count: 3,
    average: 10,
  },
  someOtherGroupName: {
    total: 60,
    count: 3,
    average: 20,
  },
};

const { someGroupName } = groups; // someGroup is Stats, that's good.

const someVariable = 'noExistKey'; 
const foundStat = groups[someVariable]; // undeinfed
It's not good and no matter what I type, foundStat will return Stats type.
```

[image]

Is that possible to check the correct type for this coding type `obj[variable]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess). It's a compiler option that makes `X[K]` return `T | undefined` instead of `T`.

```
const foundStat = groups[someVariable];
//    ^? Stat | undefined

foundStat.average // error because it could be undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=57#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjmAzsg3gWAChlkwB7DAGwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuIkhM+8Whlu07I4AN2hwA5hH5NWUDoQC+RIqEixEKAOJQeABxwFiyANog4jGcixgooSQF1a6TFkUrCRbiFvJJevSGtLoGOAC8eMJYZFahQQByltbGJCTkVLQAzAAMADTCXDx8yFkFJiRiEtK0AIz5wkrlJDFWAPJgABbQ8fpJVrSpaRlwNMgAbA0VyNy8YNnNaVVQUtYATFMkTURKit5kvmB4NrEQvf0oSsiRAWFsyAD0DydxgfrIwDiu2HmknZgAchwkjIZAAJgA6VSEHx+VoQABqcHscGYlBQkQBIDIAFEAB6fMAAaQgAE8Afd9odkDBimDvtd-G8sKZ4UiUWiII5FE80sgAHoAfmhtN49IwYAhy1Wj2e0D0UGQrAQcHoWBQwCOs0oYKVKDFEBgoAgYKAA)

Note that even when you provide the correct key i.e. `groups["someGroupName"]` it will still produce `Stat | undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, Is it the best practice for dynamic key(someVariable)?